# Need to remove numbers in parentheses and parentheses

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet in which a column has string data (names) followed by numbers in parentheses; i.e., (9815536). These numbers are not constant in length. I need to get rid of the numbers in the parentheses and the parentheses. I've tried using Columns().Cells.Replace funtion to no avail. Is there a way to use a regular expression to do this? A cell example would look like:

```
Column A
John Doe (9815536)
Sam Smith (12906)
...
```

Code I've tried looks like:

```
Columns("A:A").Select
    Selecton.Replace What:="\([0-9]*\), _
    Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: You could use a simple formula `=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1))`

Comment: or loop through the column in vba and use `cell = trim(split(cell,"(")(0))` were `cell` is the reference.

Comment: If you really want to use regex then you need to look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) on its proper usage.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to implement this is to use

- a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp)
- and a variant array in VBA.

  Using code based on my Article [Using Variant Arrays in Excel VBA for Large Scale Data Manipulation](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2684-Using-varinat-arrays-in-VBA-for-large-scale-data.html)

  ```
  Sub KillNumParen()
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim rngArea As Range
  Dim lngRow As Long
  Dim lngCol As Long
  Dim lngCalc As Long
  Dim objReg As Object
  Dim X()


  On Error Resume Next
  Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select range for the replacement of non-number", "User select", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
  If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  On Error GoTo 0

  'See Patrick Matthews excellent article on using Regular Expressions with VBA
  Set objReg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  objReg.Pattern = "\(\d+\)"
  objReg.Global = True

  'Speed up the code by turning off screenupdating and setting calculation to manual
  'Disable any code events that may occur when writing to cells
  With Application
      lngCalc = .Calculation
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      .EnableEvents = False
  End With

  'Test each area in the user selected range

  'Non contiguous range areas are common when using SpecialCells to define specific cell types to work on
  For Each rngArea In rng1.Areas
      'The most common outcome is used for the True outcome to optimise code speed
      If rngArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then
         'If there is more than once cell then set the variant array to the dimensions of the range area
         'Using Value2 provides a useful speed improvement over Value. On my testing it was 2% on blank cells, up to 10% on non-blanks
          X = rngArea.Value2
          For lngRow = 1 To rngArea.Rows.Count
              For lngCol = 1 To rngArea.Columns.Count
                  'replace the leading zeroes
                  X(lngRow, lngCol) = objReg.Replace(X(lngRow, lngCol), vbNullString)
              Next lngCol
          Next lngRow
          'Dump the updated array sans leading zeroes back over the initial range
          rngArea.Value2 = X
      Else
          'caters for a single cell range area. No variant array required
          rngArea.Value = objReg.Replace(rngArea.Value, vbNullString)
      End If
  Next rngArea

  'cleanup the Application settings
  With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .Calculation = lngCalc
      .EnableEvents = True
  End With

  Set objReg = Nothing
   End Sub
  ```